The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid. The anchor element should be part of the document layout
I am using the menu inside the DataGridPro. I am showing the three dots button for hovered row. When I am clicking on the button, menu is opening left side of the screen. And throwing the above error.
The anchorEl prop provided to the component is invalid. The anchor element should be part of the document layout.
stackblitz -> 
DataGridPro 
Menu is coming to the left side of the Screen

Here's a solution using a virtual element.
import { PopoverVirtualElement } from '@mui/material';

  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState<{
    anchorEl: PopoverVirtualElement | null;
    rowId: number | null;
  }>({ anchorEl: null, rowId: null });

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, id: number) => {
    const virtualElement: PopoverVirtualElement = { 
      nodeType: 1,
      getBoundingClientRect: () => new DOMRect(event.clientX, event.clientY, 1, 1)
    };
    setMenuState({ anchorEl: virtualElement, rowId: id });
  };

